# Making Random Active Tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs

I am new to jQuery and have managed to create a tabbed interface with 4 sections. When the page loads, the tab content of section 1 shows up and the user can click on the others links to show other sections. In other words, tab 1 is always the first to be "active." However, I want to have a random "active" tab every time the page loads, so that other sections can be "active" as well randomly. Once the page loads with the random active tab, then the user can click to look at other sections.

I would sincerely appreciate any insight on how to do this exactly. THANK YOU so much

```
<body>

<div id="tabs">

<ul>
<li><a href="#1">Tab One</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Tab Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">Tab Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">Tab Four</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="1">
<h3>Tab 1</h3>
<p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
<h3>Tab 2</h3>
<p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div id="3">
<h3>Tab 3</h3>
<p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div id="4">
<h3>Tab 4</h3>
<p>Some content</p>
</div>

</div> <!-- end tabs -->


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#tabs div').hide(); // Hide all divs
$('#tabs div:first').show(); // Show the first div
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active'); // Set the class of the first link to active
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ //When any link is clicked
$('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active'); // Remove active class from all links
$(this).parent().addClass('active'); //Set clicked link class to active
var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); // Set variable currentTab to value of href attribute of clicked link
$('#tabs div').hide(); // Hide all divs
$(currentTab).show(); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
return false;
});
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Is your code really completely un-indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs div');

$tabs.hide();

var index = Math.floor($tabs.length * Math.random());

$tabs.eq(index).show();
```

This can be condensed a bit, I have spread it out to be a bit more understandable.  I select a random number between 0 and the number of tabs -1.  Then use `eq` to filter to that numbered element.

http://jsfiddle.net/tnP3R/

Comment: Hi James, thank you so much for your quick response. How do I integrate the code correctly? Do I add it inside the <script type="text/javascript"> </script> section? Do I replace it?

Comment: Unrelated but worth noting.  I don't believe IDs are allowed to start with a number, except possibly in html5.\

Comment: It replaces the two lines that hide all tabs and then show the first.

Comment: Would have to do something similar like `$('#tabs ul li').eq(index).addClass('active');`

Comment: James - you are seriously a life saver. I appreciate your help tremendously. Last question for you - I am putting videos on each tab. If I'm on tab 1 and I click play, and then I click on tab 2, the video from tab 1 still plays. Is there a way to turn it off as I switch between tabs?

Comment: Don't deal with videos often.  That may be worth a new question on here.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number using `Math.random()` and call jQuery UI Tabs -> select method to set the desired tab.

```
var random_tab_index = Math.floor(Math.random()* $(tabSelector).tabs("length")); //will generate random number between 0 and 5
```

And then call the jQuery UI tab select function as below,

```
$(tabSelector).tabs( "select" , random_tab_index)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/AhYgg/4/)** here

Comment: Odd, didn't notice the `ui` tag on the question.  I don't actually see any indication that he's using `ui-tabs`.  Wonder if the tag is incorrect.

Comment: @James Montagne: wow, i missed the whole script part and assumed that it was jQuery UI tabs.. :(

Comment: SKS - thank you so much!!!!!! Your script is exactly what I want. But I would need to use the jQuery UI tabs to get it to work, correct? I am not able to get it to work by just copying your code.

Comment: Yes, you need to download the jQuery UI tabs js and css to make it work.